# MongoDB find documents that matches either any of the conditions specified using aggregation

Tags: datatables, aggregation, php-mongodb

I'm creating a text-search function in datatable using aggregation.

```
$ops = array(      
  array(
    '$match' => array(                              
        "status" => "A",                    
        '$or' => array(
                array("team" => "Golz"),
                array("rank" => "freshmen")
        )                   
  )
)
```

Translated to mysql, it's "select * from dbname where status='A' AND (team='Golz' OR rank='freshmen').

DB returns nothing, where it should be returning several items.

WHat seems to be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

i seem to have a work-around and here's how i did it.

using $or inside find() which returns cursor obj. using the cursor obj, i pass the id to the or inside the match aggregate. so inside my match array i have something like this:

```
 '$match' => array(                              
    "status" => "A",                    
    '$or' => array(
            array("id" => "1"),
            array("id" => "2"),
            array("id" => "3")
    )
```